# Why can't I find '__path__' in django.db.__init__.py?

Tags: python, django

```
backend_dir = os.path.join(__path__[0], 'backends')
```

Why can't I find it?

Comment: What would you expect? What output do you actually get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `settings.DATABASE_ENGINE` in `settings.py`.

The execution reaches the line you mentioned only if the back-end is not standard.